# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createConnection')

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeerror

New to node.js and just trying to establish a connection to a mysql database hosted on Azure. The below is all I am trying to do without getting the TypeError of death.

using

```json
"mysql": "^2.18.1"
```

The below is the entire code base I am trying to get to run without error.

```js
const { mysql } = require('mysql');

var sqlConfig = {
    host        : '*****************',
    port        : 3306,
    user        : '*****',
    password    : '**********',
    database    : '*******'
};

var connection = mysql.createConnection(sqlConfig);
```

What am I missing?

Not sure what else to try. Just following the code example to acquire the connection. I am just expecting the app to return without errors.

Comment: The [mysql library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#introduction) has a default export, not a named one. Just use `const mysql = require('mysql')`. Why were you destructuring it anyway?

Comment: Good question. Just copied that code off the internet in an example use. But that solved it. Thank you.